# Added a field to a model, how do I update the database to changes to the model

Tags: django, django-south

All I did was add a field to a model, and now I get an error that says this column does not exist.

In an attempt to rebuild the database I used -flush (i dont care about losing the data), thinking this would rebuild the database, but I still get the same error.

I was told by someone else to use South because I'm running Django 1.6.
I followed the tutorial and literally the first time I ran syncdb, I got the following (probably unrelated) error:

```
dist-packages/easy-thumbnails/
raise Improperly_Configured(SOUTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:

For South Support, customize the SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES setting like so:

South_Migration_Module = {
'easy_thumbnails': 'easy_thumbnails.south_migrations',
}
```

Ultimately all I want to do is have my db reflect my models.  Back when I was working on this project in my dev environment I would literally just drag my sqlite file to the trash and then run syncdb, but I cannot do that now because I'm using postgres.

So my question is how can I accomplish this seemingly simple task?  Whether that means addressing the South error, or just not using South altogether (which I would prefer), I would appreciated any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually open up a db shell (`>>> python manage.py dbshell`) and drop the table with `DROP TABLE <table_name>;`. In order for `syncdb` to recreate a table with the new field, it is not enough to empty the table.

To solve the error, just do exactly what it says: add the `SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES` setting to your settings.

With that said, I'd definitely advice you to use south. It eases making changes to your models, and it allows you to preserve test data in your development environment that you'd otherwise have to recreate. That's all nice, but when your project goes live, it is absolutely mandatory that your data is preserved when making a change to your models. South is the best tool for that.

South has been such an integral part of pretty much any Django project, that Django has worked together with the developers of South to include it as a core feature from Django 1.7 onwards.

Comment: I added the SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES setting, and that got rid of the error I was getting when I run syncdb, however now I get a new error when following the South tutorial.  The error says that a relation already exists.  Not sure why I've had a nightmarish time with South.  At this point I am going to disable south (hopefully removed it from installed apps is enough) and try to drop the table in sql.

Comment: Updated with the `DROP TABLE` command. Have you followed the instructions on [converting an app](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app)?

Comment: I followed those exact instructions.

Comment: I tried using south on this project 6 months ago and had a hard time back then too, so I'm wondering if this current error is related to that.  Like maybe I have some remnants of south inside of my project.  Who knows..

Comment: That could very well be the problem. Try deleting the `migrations/` folder in each app.

Comment: I don't have a migrations folder in my app or even in my project folder!  I really don't understand why I'm having such a hard time with this.